# `type *var = (int)0`, legal or not?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, language-lawyer

The following example:

```
char *var = (int)0;
```

Compiles on gcc and cl.exe, but causes an error in clang:

> cannot initialize a variable of type 'char *' with an rvalue of type 'int'

Who is correct here?

---

For what it's worth, C++11 says (emphasis mine)

> 4.10/1
>
> A null pointer constant is an **integral constant expression** (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type and ...

And

> 5.19/3
>
> An integral constant expression is a literal constant expression of integral or unscoped enumeration type. [ Note: Such expressions may be used as array bounds (8.3.4, 5.3.4), as bit-field lengths (9.6), as enumerator initializers if the underlying type is not fixed (7.2), as null pointer constants (4.10), and as alignments (7.6.2). — end note ]

From what I understand, the above code should be illegal. cl.exe notoriously violates the standard (so I don't trust it a bit), but gcc also accepts the above code. Are there other parts of the standard relevant that I'm missing or is that outright a gcc bug?

Comment: Are you using GCC correctly at all? I.e. are you using `-pedantic -Wall -std=c++14`? GCC is not an easy compiler to use correctly for novices.

Comment: `char *var = (int)0;` is not the same as `char *var = 0;` or `char *var = nullptr;`

Comment: @KerrekSB, I ran it with `-Wall -std=c++11 -pedantic`. (gcc 6.2.0)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, did I claim that it is?

Comment: @Shahbaz No, but the explicit type cast may make a difference for the compiler.

Comment: It would be nice if you could include the relevant gcc/clang/cl.exe versions

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ hence the question whether that is still legal or it's a gcc bug.

Comment: @Rakete1111, gcc 6.2.0, visual studio 2015 (update 3) and clang 3.7.1 (unfortunately old)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Originally, in C++11, this was legal because the wording was:

> A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero

But, as of [CWG defect 903](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#903), which is a defect against C++11, it became not legal:

> A null pointer constant is an integer literal (2.13.2 [lex.icon]) with value zero

`(int)0` is an integral constant expression prvalue of integer type that evalutes to zero, but it's not literally an integer literal with value `0`.

As this is a defect against C++11, the code itself should be ill-formed in C++11.

Comment: Interesting. g++ with `-std=c++14` still accepts this though

Comment: The "status" of the issue seems to say pretty clearly that this has been accepted as a DR, doesn't it? So it's now always been part of C++11 and later :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB What does "This issue has been returned to "review" status to allow discussion of whether to accommodate such code or not." mean? And how do you know if if it's a DR against C++11 or just a fix for C++14?

Comment: I don't know what the comment means, but the status has been and continues to be "CD3", so it applies to everything since C++11. Whatever the comment was referring to did not seem to have affected the resolution, as far as I can tell. (Details could of course be dug up if needed.)

Comment: @KerrekSB, Barry, What is the final verdict here then, is it legal in C++11 or not?

Comment: @Shahbaz: No, it is not.

Comment: DR 903 is retroactive to C++11. This appears to be yet another case of GCC folding things too early.

Comment: "And how do you know if if it's a DR against C++11 or just a fix for C++14?" Newer Core issues have the annotation "[Moved to DR status at the April, 2013 meeting.]" at the top.

Comment: @T.C. I... don't know what that means.

Comment: @Barry For more recently resolved issues (roughly since C++11, IIRC), Core distinguishes between defect reports (de facto retroactive) and other issues/extensions (not retroactive). The former has a "Moved to DR status" annotation on top - although it looks like the issue list maintainer is getting sloppy again...

Comment: @barry, since nobody else responded, care to update your answer (which seems it's not legal since C++11 anymore, not C++14) so I can accept it?

Comment: @Shahbaz Updated.